# Execute the rake task for longer data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake-task

I have one rake task to update the fields(say for img_name) in the database. In my data base i have more than 75,000 records. If i run the rake task means its taking more than 1hour to complete the rake task. I want to run the rake task for every 10,000 records. I Mean for first time 10,000 records, second time next 10,000 records and so on. Can any one help me out? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any sort of background job gem that you are using (eg. delayed_job)?  If so, I would have a rake task that creates a bunch of background jobs to do the work.

If you have an array you are iterating through, you could do it like:

```
items.in_groups_of(10000, false) do |batch|
  # create background job for this batch
end
```

If it's a collection, you can use something like:

```
@items.find_in_batches(batch_size: 10000) do |batch|
  # create background job for this batch
end
```